# Show Wait Screen WindowsPhone8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Some operation in my application takes some time, i want to show the wait screen so that the user may not do anything till the operation completes.

Kindly let me know how can i do so.

Answer (score 1):

You may edit Frame template and insert special control in this way:

```
<Style x:Key="mainFrameStyle" TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationFrame">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationFrame">
            <Border x:Name="ClientArea" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                    <Grid x:Name="mainFrameGrid">
                        <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />

                        <Grid Background="Black" Visibility="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource TrueToVisibleConverter}, Source={StaticResource FrameViewModel}}">
                            <TextBlock Text="Loading.." VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and apply this template in App.xaml.cs in InitializePhoneApplication() using this code:

```
    RootFrame = new TransitionFrame();
    RootFrame.Style = Resources["mainFrameStyle"] as Style;
```

So all you need is register some viewmodel as a staticresource and change it's IsBusy property when needed.

Comment: thanks, i will definitely use it. is it possible that we use the Telerik control lib for this? i mean is there any mechanism available in telerik controls?